# Changing Salesforce report filters through url - change the Filter Logic too?

Tags: reporting, salesforce

In Salesforce there is a way to programmably filter reports by adding parameters to the report url. pc#, pn# and pv# allow filters 0 to 9 (reports have a max of 10 filters) to be modified or even created out of nothing (a report with no filters have can have filters dynamically added like this).

In addition to the 10 generic filters it is also possibe to add a single "Filter Logic" filter/rule to the report. A typical filter logic rule might be "1 AND (2 OR 3)", which means filter 1 must be true, and either filter 2 or 3 must be true.

Is there any way to change this through url manipulation like with parameters? Or am I stuck with hard coding the filters 99% of the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url parameter is

bool_filter

you'll need to urlencode the value you want, so it's going to look more like

bool_filter=1%20or%202